# select multiple columns by checkboxGroupInput in R shiny

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, grepl

I have a question about how to select multiple columns in my dataset by checkboxGroupInput in R shiny.

Now my dataset have a column like this: (the pattern is stateName/number/number)

IndividualName

SA/111111/222222

VIC/33333/444444

NSW/55555/666666

QLD/777777/888888

.....

and I have a select box that works well. I use grepl to extract state name and I can choose individual state successfully.

UI:

```
        selectInput("select_state", h3("Select State"),
                choices = list("All States"="SA|VIC|NSW|QLD|WA|TAS|NT|ACT|CTH","South Australia"="SA",
                               "Victoria"="VIC","New South Wales"="NSW","Queensland"="QLD",
                               "Western Australia"="WA","Northern Territory"="NT","Tasmania"="TAS",
                               "Australian Capital Territory"="ACT","Commonwealth"="CTH")),
```

Server:

```
entities_state <- entities[ with(entities, grepl(input$select_state, c(entities$IndividualName))), ]
```

Now I want to change the select box to checkbox group, I know to use checkbox group, we can write

```
entities_state <-filter(entities, IndividualName %in% input$select_state)
```

but I still need extract stateName keyword from the "IndividualName" column. I don't know how to combine grepl, filter, and %n% to make the checkbox group work.

I hope I express my problem clearly. If not, please let me know.

Comment: You can directly use `grepl` instead of `%in%` if you need a partial match. i.e. `filter(entities, grepl(input$select_state, IndividualName))` But, it looks like the conditions are the same except you are using `base R` syntax earlier and change it to `dplyr::filter`

Comment: `entities_state <- dplyr::filter(entities, grepl(input$select_state, IndividualName))`

Comment: What is the issue with that syntax

Comment: Thank you so much! Akrun. After I changed my code to `dplyr::filter(entities, grepl(input$select_state, IndividualName))`, there is a problem. When I select all states, my dataset only shows rows with SA. Then I unselect SA, the dataset shows rows with VIC. Then I unselect VIC, the dataset shows row with NSW......  I can't get rows with multiple states. I hope I describe clearly.

Comment: I think in the `selectInput` you need `multiple = TRUE`

Comment: I added multiple = TRUE, but there is still the same problem. I can get rows with only one state, not multiple states.

Comment: I am thinking that `filter(entities, grepl(input$select_state, IndividualName))` helps select one state, if we use %n% or other similar function, it will help select multiple states?

Comment: You need `grepl(paste(input$select_state, collapse="|"), IndividualName)`

Comment: Thank you! It works. We can use paste to get multiple states! Smart! You help me a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The `pattern` for `grepl` can be made using`paste` and `collapse` with `|` so that it will check for either one of the choices that were selected with `select_state`

```
i1 <- grepl(paste(input$select_state, collapse="|"), entities$IndividualName)
library(dplyr)
entities %>%
           filter(i1)
```

or we can create it within the `filter`

```
entities %>% 
         filter(grepl(paste(input$select_state, collapse="|"), IndividualName))
```